# Can elasticsearch handle structured data whats its limits?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have got 5 million objects.Each object has 100 properties. 50 properties text, 40 properties numeric values and ten properties datetime. I am sending random ad hoc queries with sorts and all kinds of queries. What ES limits? How big can the cluster go ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll get a precise answer as to how big ES can go - as always it's a question of what kind of documents you are indexing, the complexity of the queries, the frequency with which you update and query, what acceptable response times are, etc.

That said, from my own experience of several live clusters with hundreds of millions of documents each I'd say you are well below any known limits to ES. I'd also check their list of cases studies, should give you more insight into how others are using ES.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/case-studies/

Comment: Agreed. Depends on the hardware as well. Needs testing with your own hardware, documents and queries, especially to decide how many shards you need etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the limitations of Apache Lucene rather than Elasticsearch seeing as ES is essentially Lucene in a big wrapper. You can start by having a look [here](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene40/package-summary.html#Limitations). Hope this helps.

Comment: Elasticsearch creates multiple Lucene instances though, as every shard is effectively a Lucene index.